# Get Keyboard size in textFieldShouldBeginEditing delegate

Tags: ios, iphone, uikeyboard

I am having trouble while i am creating a messaging app, When keyboard is opened i am not sure about total size and frame for Keyboard (dictionary area is opened or not).
I want to get total size and frame in

> textFieldShouldBeginEditing

delegate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification . Also make sure to convert the CGRect into the proper view, for landscape use.

Set NSNotificationCenter in your `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChange:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

and write this method.

```
- (void)keyboardWillChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGRect keyboardRect = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    keyboardRect = [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil]; //this is it!
}
```

In Swift 4

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(_noti:) ), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame , object: nil)
```

KeyboardWillChange Method

```
@objc func keyboardWillChange(_noti:NSNotification)
{
    let keyBoard = _noti.userInfo
    let keyBoardValue = keyBoard![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]
    let fram = keyBoardValue as? CGRect // this is frame
}
```

Comment: It's the handling of the keyboard rect under rotation that is the valuable part of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Register for UIKeyboardWillShowNotification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

and in the selector get the keyboard frame:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)iNotification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [iNotification userInfo];
    NSValue *aValue = [userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardRect = [aValue CGRectValue];
}
```

Comment: Got it!, But i am wonder i an setting the frame when it is tapped on UITextField how i can set this every time? delegates called

Answer (score 4):

I have faced this problem and solved by using notification observer on keyboard.

```
//set observer in textFieldShouldBeginEditing like    
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myNotificationMethod:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
    return YES;
}

// method implementation
- (void)myNotificationMethod:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",keyboardFrameBegin);

    NSLog(@"%f",keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height);
}

//remove observer
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter ]removeObserver:self];    
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much i guess i complete my problem :)